# Struts2 Tiles in Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, struts2, tiles

I am trying to build an java web application using struts2 and tiles in Google App Engine. Below is my tiles.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

<definition name="baseLayout" template="BaseLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="Header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="Footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="/welcome.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="Welcome.jsp" />
</definition>




</tiles-definitions>
```

But when I run the app,I am not getting any error. it just prints "Header.jsp Welcome.jsp Footer.jsp". It does not show the actual jsp pages. Please advise on what needs to be done.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: You need to provide more information. What versions of S2/Tiles? What does the layout JSP look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to place `"/"` with your included jsp files, hence instead of fetching the content of relevant files it is displaying them as text.

Correct format should look like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="BaseLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/Header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/Footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="/welcome.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/Welcome.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```